# Selecting Custom Field from RSS feed

Tags: python, rss

So I'm trying to select the information within a custom feed from an RSS file. So far I'm making use of feed parser to access more common fields within the file. I was wondering if anyone would know how to achieve this given that there are numerous custom fields. The specific custom field i'm trying to select is the venue address.

```
        <item>
        <title>First 5 Forever babies, books and rhymes</title>
        <description>Thursday, June 9, 2022, 9:30&amp;nbsp;&amp;ndash;&amp;nbsp;10am &lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;img src="https://www.trumba.com/i/DgBXwGE0qzQ0Bl7V7ynz3DTV.jpg" title="First 5 Forever babies, books and rhymes" 
        <link>https://www.brisbane.qld.gov.au/trumba?trumbaEmbed=view%3devent%26eventid%3d159467519</link>
        <x-trumba:ealink>https://eventactions.com/eventactions/brisbane-city-council#/actions/030ma0wxb5wympxw4nud1vrr72</x-trumba:ealink>
        <category>2022/06/09 (Thu)</category>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://uid.trumba.com/event/159467519</guid>
        <x-trumba:masterid isPermaLink="false">http://uid.trumba.com/master/159467517</x-trumba:masterid>
        <xCal:summary>First 5 Forever babies, books and rhymes</xCal:summary>
        <xCal:location>Nundah Library</xCal:location>
        <xCal:dtstart>2022-06-08T23:30:00Z</xCal:dtstart>
        <x-trumba:localstart tzAbbr="EAST" tzCode="260">2022-06-09T09:30:00</x-trumba:localstart>
        <x-trumba:formatteddatetime>Thursday, June 9, 2022, 9:30 - 10am</x-trumba:formatteddatetime>
        <xCal:dtend>2022-06-09T00:00:00Z</xCal:dtend>
        <x-trumba:localend tzAbbr="EAST" tzCode="260">2022-06-09T10:00:00</x-trumba:localend>
        <x-microsoft:cdo-alldayevent>false</x-microsoft:cdo-alldayevent>
        <x-trumba:customfield name="Event Type" id="21" type="number">Library events</x-trumba:customfield>
        <x-trumba:customfield name="Venue" id="22542" type="text">Nundah Library</x-trumba:customfield>
        <x-trumba:customfield name="Venue address" id="22505" type="text">Nundah Library, 1 Bage Street (via Primrose Lane), Nundah</x-trumba   :customfield>
        <x-trumba:customfield name="Parent event" id="42212" type="text">First 5 Forever children's literacy sessions</x-trumba:customfield>
        <x-trumba:customfield name="Age range" id="21858" type="text">Infants and toddlers</x-trumba:customfield>
        <x-trumba:customfield name="Cost" id="22177" type="text">Free</x-trumba:customfield>
        <x-trumba:customfield name="Event type" id="21859" type="text">Free</x-trumba:customfield>
        <x-trumba:customfield name="Library event types" id="22496" type="text">Babies, books &amp; rhymes,Children's literacy</x-trumba:customfield>
        <x-trumba:customfield name="Event image" id="40" type="uri" imageWidth="1290" imageHeight="775">https://www.trumba.com/i/DgBXwGE0qzQ0Bl7V7ynz3DTV.jpg</x-trumba:customfield>
        <x-trumba:customfield name="Age" id="23562" type="text">0-1 year olds</x-trumba:customfield>
        <x-trumba:categorycalendar>Brisbane's calendar|Library events</x-trumba:categorycalendar>
```

Examples of the code I have used previously to retrieve information can be seen below:

```
blog_feed = feedparser.parse(url)
posts = blog_feed.entries
for post in posts:
    #collecting the title for each individual item in the RSS file
    title = post.title
    #selecting the entire item as "word"
    word = posts[counter]
    counter = counter+1
    #we know that the date of the event is always stored after the code (category)
    date = word.category
```

After attempting to use BS4 I can successfully retrieve the address, but I am still unsure if it is possible to make use of this method within a loop to find the address of each item within the RSS file and then append the address to a main list given another parameter is true.

```
with open("brisbane-city-council.rss") as fp:
soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, "html.parser")
addrress = soup.find("x-trumba:customfield", id="22505")
print(addrress)
```

Below is the for loop I am using.

```
for post in posts:
    #collecting the title for each individual item in the RSS file
    title = post.title
    #selecting the entire item as "word"
    word = posts[counter]
    counter = counter+1
    #we know that the date of the event is always stored after the code (category)
    date = word.category
    #pulling down the link as it is unique for each event
    link = word.link
    #formatting date for ease of use and to allow functionality to be completed
    date = date.split(' (')
    date = date[0]
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y/%m/%d").date()
    if date > start_date and date < end_date:
        post_list.append(title)
        description = post.summary
        h = html2text.HTML2Text()
        h.ignore_links = True
        description = h.handle(description)
        description_list.append(description)
        link_list.append(link)
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Could you clarify which elements you're trying to extract and having problems extracting? And also show the code where you're having the problem? 
  In terms of other tools that you may find useful, BeautifulSoup4's html.parser should be able to parse the custom fields.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety I added some more information in the post, hopefully this clarifies things for you.

Comment: From looking at the provided sample files from Brisbane, it looks like using BS the way you are, checking for `"x-trumba:customfield", id="22505"` is the best way to go.  The custom field ids appear to be consistent for all entries whether in the RSS or the JSON feed.   It should be doable in a loop, but neither of your loop examples show how you are integrating bs or the rss feed.  I think you would want to use BS to find all <item> tags, loop over those, and then parse each one separately.  Note, some entries might not have all custom fields.